# Flexslider fit to window height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexslider

I'm using the Flexslider (v.1.8). I wanted to create a fullscreen image slider on my homepage.

I want to fit the slider to the window (inner)size of the browser. I've played something with de width:100% and the height:auto. The width works but the height not properly because the image height is fit to my screen resolution (so its bigger then my usual window of my browser) but i want to fit it to the height of my window.

Is there a solution for that, and an explanation ?

THnx

Comment: [This answer might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19321599/439642)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `height:100%;` then wouldn't it fit the height of the browser? If you want to make sure there is no part off the screen give it an ID and make a link to that `#id`. Make sure there is no `padding:` or `margin:` since then the image might not fit properly. BTW you haven't explained it very well, it needs much more detail, at least some code.